# Using Jquery to filter my attribute values[EE 1.14.0]

Tags: filtered-nav, filterable-attributes

Alright so I am about 2/3 the way through this problem. I have implemented :

https://github.com/jaschahal/jcTextHighlighterFilter/blob/master/jcFilter/jquery/jcfilter.js

In order to be able to use a input field to search my attribute values.

I added the parameters needed to `catalog\layer\view.phtml`

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery("#filter").jcOnPageFilter({animateHideNShow: false,
                    focusOnLoad:true,
                    highlightColor:'yellow',
                    textColorForHighlights:'#000000',
                    caseSensitive:false,
                    hideNegatives:true,
                    parentLookupClass:'jcorgFilterTextParent',
                    childBlockClass:'jcorgFilterTextChild'});
       });
```

and then in catalog\layer\filter.phtml I tagged my list items with the parent and child classes.

```
<ol> <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li class="jcorgFilterTextParent">
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>" class="jcorgFilterTextChild">
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span>
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li> <?php endforeach ?> </ol>
```

Here is a frontend to get better picture of what I am doing.
[image]

my problem is that by directly injecting the parent child classes in the filter.phtml its adding the parent and child classes to all attributes at once. Which means the function only works on the first attribute on every page. Can I use a php if statement to refer to an *active* class [used for the accordion style menu], and only add the parent child class on 'active' list items?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I got this figured out. Instead of adding class names to the filter.phtml I added the class names with jquery in my list-category.phtml

here is the solution:

```
//Script for filter navigation
jQuery('.block-layered-nav .block-content #narrow-by-list dt').on('click', function (){
    if(jQuery(this).next('dd').css('display') != 'block'){
        jQuery('.active input').removeAttr('id');
        jQuery('.active li').removeClass('jcorgFilterTextParent');
        jQuery('.active a').removeClass('jcorgFilterTextChild');
        jQuery('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');

        jQuery(this).next('dd').addClass('active').slideDown('slow');
        jQuery('.active input').attr('id' ,'filter');
        jQuery('.active li').addClass('jcorgFilterTextParent');
        jQuery('.active a').addClass('jcorgFilterTextChild');
        jQuery("#filter").jcOnPageFilter({animateHideNShow: false,
                  focusOnLoad:true,
                  highlightColor:'yellow',
                  textColorForHighlights:'#000000',
                  caseSensitive:false,
                  hideNegatives:true,
                  parentLookupClass:'jcorgFilterTextParent',
                  childBlockClass:'jcorgFilterTextChild'});

    } else {
        jQuery('.active input').removeAttr('id');
        jQuery('.active li').removeClass('jcorgFilterTextParent');
        jQuery('.active a').removeClass('jcorgFilterTextChild');
        jQuery('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');

    }


});
```

});

Comment: can you please update anyone working code. i also need this

Comment: ok I will revisit this it has been working for some time so Ill get a full explainer in here as soon as I get the chance.